# Inserting google maps api into ionic template page

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I'm new in ionic but I would try convert my old app into this powerfull framework.
I'll try to use google maps api into a template page loaded.

this is my app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.mappa', {
      url: "/mappa",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/mappa.html",
          controller: 'MarkerRemoveCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.search', {
      url: "/search",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/search.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.registrati', {
      url: "/registrati",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/registrati.html"
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.browse', {
      url: "/browse",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/browse.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.playlists', {
      url: "/playlists",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/playlists.html",
          controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.single', {
      url: "/playlists/:playlistId",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/playlist.html",
          controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.prova', {
      url: "/prova",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/prova.html"
        }
      }
    });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
});
```

and this is my controller.js

```
    angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {
  $scope.loginData = {};
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {

  scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  $scope.closeLogin = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  $scope.login = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  $scope.doLogin = function() {
    console.log('Eseguo la login', $scope.loginData);

    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.closeLogin();
    }, 1000);
  };
})

.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.playlists = [
    { title: 'Reggae', id: 1 },
    { title: 'Chill', id: 2 },
    { title: 'Dubstep', id: 3 },
    { title: 'Indie', id: 4 },
    { title: 'Rap', id: 5 },
    { title: 'Cowbell', id: 6 }
  ];
})

.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
})

.controller('MarkerRemoveCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {
  $scope.positions = [{
    lat: 43.07493,
    lng: -89.381388
  }];
  $scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(event, map) {
    $scope.map = map;
  });
  $scope.centerOnMe= function(){
  $scope.positions = [];

    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: 'Loading...'
    });
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      $scope.positions.push({lat: pos.k,lng: pos.B});
      console.log(pos);
      $scope.map.setCenter(pos);
      $ionicLoading.hide();
    });
  };
});
```

and then this is my index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
</html>
```

As you understand I would that when i click on "mappa" button, I open mappa.html template and load the map!

mappa.html

```
<ion-view ng-controller="MarkerRemoveCtrl">
<ion-content scroll="false">
  <div class="mapWrap"  data-tap-disabled="true">
    <map center="43.07493,-89.381388" zoom="15">
      <!-- ngRepeat: pos in positions -->
      <marker ng-repeat=" pos in positions" position="{{pos.lat}},{{pos.lng}}"></marker>
    </map>
  </div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

But nothing happen!
I'll try putting the mappa.html code into index, and all works fine!

The question is:
is possible to load maps in other template page, or only in main page?
And how to?

**UPDATE SOLUTION**

Ok I solved my problem so just calling init()

this is maps.html

```
<ion-view title="MAPPA" ng-init="init()">
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-energized"></ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
  </ion-content>
  <ion-footer-bar class="bar-dark"> <a ng-click="centerOnMe()" class="button button-icon icon ion-navigate">Dove mi trovo</a> </ion-footer-bar>
</ion-view>
```

And this is the controller:

```
//MAPPE
.controller('mapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) { 
      $scope.init = function() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493,-89.381388);
        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            mapOptions);

        //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
        var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Clicca qui!</a></div>";
        var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: compiled[0]
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
        $scope.map = map;
    };
    // google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    $scope.centerOnMe = function() {
        if(!$scope.map) {return;}

        $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
          content: 'Getting current location...',
          showBackdrop: false
        });

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
          $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
          $scope.loading.hide();
        }, function(error) {
          alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
        });
    };
    $scope.clickTest = function() {
        alert('Example of infowindow with ng-click')
    };
})
```

For me work fine, and when clicking find correct position and show on the maps!
thanks!

Comment: FYI: This plugin helps you to embed native Google Map into your app.  Many ionic framework users use this plugin.  https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you are using Google Maps JavaScript library, if you are using v3 API then you need to specify API Key if not then you may want to try PhoneGap plugin for native Google maps that will load much faster on mobile devices.

The code you posted looks a little weird to me, you may want to post simpler version here. But i don't see anywhere in your code that you are setting map to load in mapWrap div, you should definitely do that.